# "Trust anchor for certification path not found" in Android SSL Socket client

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm trying to connect to an SSL Server using an Android client app.
The server has its JKS certificate which was converted to BKS using Portecle.
Server code is very simple:

```
public class EchoServer {
public static void main(String[] arstring) {
    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(25000);
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

        InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        String string = null;
        while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(string);
            System.out.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Server works properly (I tested it with a java client app using the same certificate and it showed no problem).
Now, I converted the JKS server certificate in a BKS certificate using Portecle, but Android is unable to connect to the server.
Android code looks like

```
            InputStream certificato = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
            KeyStore trustStore = null;
            try {
                String tfmAlgorithm=TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
                trustStore.load(certificato, "123456".toCharArray());
                TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tfmAlgorithm);
                tmf.init(trustStore);
                SSLContext slc=SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                slc.init(null,tmf.getTrustManagers(),new SecureRandom());
                SSLSocketFactory fs=slc.getSocketFactory();
                Socket socket = fs.createSocket("10.0.0.2", 25000);

                /*InputStream inputstream = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);*/

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                String sendMessage = "brova";
                bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                bw.flush();

                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : " + sendMessage);
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "OK";
        }
```

It should work, because it's the same code I use on the Java PC client, but it raises this exception stack:

```
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:375)
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:669)
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getOutputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:606)
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.furt.myapplication.MyActivity$richiestaServer.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:235)
10-31 00:05:09.068   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.furt.myapplication.MyActivity$richiestaServer.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:166)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:192)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:163)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:574)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:372)
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 11 more
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
10-31 00:05:09.078   9921-10142/com.example.furt.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 16 more
10-31 00:05:09.128    9921-9921/com.example.furt.myapplication D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x50f8b000 size:61440 offset:0 fd:80
10-31 00:05:09.128    9921-9921/com.example.furt.myapplication D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4f274000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:82
10-31 00:05:11.088    9921-9921/com.example.furt.myapplication D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x50f8b000 size:61440
10-31 00:05:11.088    9921-9921/com.example.furt.myapplication D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4f274000 size:4096
10-31 00:06:11.878    9921-9921/com.example.furt.myapplication I/InputMethodManager﹕ startInput, mServedView=android.widget.EditText@417e4420, inputType=0x81, pid=9921
```

Can anyone explain why? I've read around that often ŧhe "Trust anchor for certificate path not found" is due to a missing TrustManager, but my code should refer to the TrustManagerFactory which uses my certificate.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you using Apache or HttpsUrlConnection? Looks like Apache right? Why set to SSL rather than TLS?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
I'm using Apache. Actually it was originally set to TLS, I switched to SSL just to try if it worked. Setting the socket to TLS won't work either.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I am facing a similar problem.